# What additional features of an SDK differentiates it from a class lib a single developer creates?

Tags: coding-style

Simply..
What differentiates a class library/code library ( a developer makes in general for his projects ) from an SDK. ( Isn't it a massive class library only ? )

Thanks
V.

Comment: ok, sry!.. added to coding-style tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK is generally a set of libraries, together with documentation, tools and other goodies that are helpful for a developer wishing to build his application using your code. That said, not every project's output can be considered an SDK. Some projects will just provide you with library.